# Prove the induction axiom via the induction rule

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, peano-axioms

Consider the formal system $P'$ which is the same as $PA$, but without all the induction axioms and with an additional *induction rule*:

> If $\vdash A_x[0]$ and $\vdash A\to A_x[Sx]$, then $\vdash A$.

Let $A$ be the induction axiom $B_x[0]\wedge\forall x(B\to B_x[Sx])\to B$ for $B$. I am trying to prove $A$ in $P'$. In the book it is stated as something trivial that $A_x[0]$ and $A\to A_x[Sx]$ are provable without use of induction axioms, hence $\vdash_{P'}A$ by the induction rule. **I don't see how $A\to A_x[Sx]$ is provable.**

Here is my approach. The deduction theorem holds in $P'$ since $P'$ has all the rules and axioms used in its proof. We have $\vdash_{P'[B_x[0],\forall x(B\to B_x[Sx])]}B$ by the generalization and induction rules, hence $\vdash_{P'} A$ by the deduction theorem. **Is this approach correct?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your symbols, $A$ is $B_x[0] ∧ ∀x(B → B_x[Sx]) → B$.

This means that $A_x[0]$ will be:

> $(B_x[0] ∧ ∀x(B → B_x[Sx]) → B)_x[0]$.

But $x$ does not occur *free* into: $B_x[0] ∧ ∀x(B → B_x[Sx])$ and thus $A_x[0]$ will be:

> $B_x[0] ∧ ∀x(B → B_x[Sx]) → B_x[0]$.

This formula is like $P \land Q \to P$, which is valid, i.e. it is provable in $P'$ without arithmetical axioms.

In conclusion:

> > $\vdash_{P'} A_x[0]$.

---

*The second part is a little more tricky*...

We have to prove:

> $(B_x[0] ∧ ∀x(B → B_x[Sx])→B) \to (B_x[0] ∧ ∀x(B → B_x[Sx]) → B_x[Sx])$.

Assume the antecedent: $B_x[0] ∧ ∀x(B → B_x[Sx]) → B$, and assume $B_x[0] ∧ ∀x(B → B_x[Sx])$.

By *Modus Ponens*: $B$, and using *Simplification* and *UI* we have: $B → B_x[Sx]$.

Using *MP* again: $B_x[Sx]$.

Now, the result follows by *DT*:

> > $\vdash_{P'} A \to A_x[Sx]$.

Comment: Thank you! Since we are using the deduction theorem anyway my approach seems to be simpler, but is it correct?

Comment: @Ansar - Yes... **provided that** you have the derivation $B_x[0], \forall x (B \to B_x[Sx]) \vdash_{P'} B$. As said in your book, "the result is obvious": IMO, the gist of the exercise is to write the needed derivation.